# Make space between rows constant

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize, displaystyle

Consider this toy example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)}$
    \item $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)}$
    \item $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)}$
    \item $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^N i^2}$
    \item $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This gives the following output:

[image]

Is there a "correct" way to make the distance between the bullets to be constant? I know I can use some trick like

```
\begin{itemize}
\itemsep2ex
    \item $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)}$
    \item $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)}$
    \item $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)}$
    \item \vspace{-4mm} $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^N i^2}$\vspace{-2mm}
    \item $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)}$
\end{itemize}
```

which gives a better looking solution:

[image]

But this doesn't seem the proper way to go (also because it requires me to estimate the spaces by visual inspection). Is there a way to force the distance between bullets to be constant?

Comment: Do you have, in general, only a singular item that doesn't fit in with the rest?

Comment: Yes, I think I never find myself in the situation of having more than one item that doesn't fit in with the others. A general solution is probably better, but I'd appreciate also a workaround for this special case.

Comment: Probably it has to be said that the main reason that tex has textstyle and displaystyle math mode is to avoid this problem, textstyle using a cramped style to avoid disturbing the line spacing, so by using `\displaystyle` you are explicitly opting out of the built in mechanism and have to add manual corrections as needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps a combination of things are needed here:

- Reducing the height of the odd-one-out formula using `\smash`; this will actually make it have a height/depth of `0pt`.
- Substituting the odd-one-out height for something else using `\vphantom{<stuff>}`; this will not print `<stuff>`, but instead insert a box of zero width with height/depth of `<stuff>`... like a vertical strut.
- Adjusting `itemsep` to make the visual appearance acceptable; [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) works easiest for this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
  \item $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$
  \item $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$
  \item $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N i^2$
  \item $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
  \item $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$
  \item $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$
  \item $\displaystyle \vphantom{\lim_{x_0}}\smash{\sum_{i=1}^N i^2}$
  \item $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=2ex]
  \item $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$
  \item $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$
  \item $\displaystyle \vphantom{\lim_{x_0}}\smash{\sum_{i=1}^N i^2}$
  \item $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The left list is an original, unadjusted list. The middle list uses `\smash` to remove the height/depth of the `\sum` but also inserts a `\vphantom` of the tallest item in the remainder of the list (in this case, `\displaystyle\lim_{x_0}`). The right list adds some vertical space between items by setting `itemsep=2ex`.

Answer (score 1):

This is tailor made for a TABstack.  Here, `30pt` is selected as the inter-item baselineskip, and `2ex` is selected as the left/right gap between the bullet and the material itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}[2016-10-04]
\begin{document}
\setstackgap{L}{30pt}
\TABstackMath
\TABstackMathstyle{\displaystyle}
\setstacktabulargap{2ex}
\protect\tabularLongstack{cl}{
    \bullet & \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\\
    \bullet & \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\\
    \bullet & \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\\
    \bullet & \sum_{i=1}^N i^2\\
    \bullet & \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Caveat: Does not allow line-breaking within the "list".

Comment: @Werner, not so.  One can use a stack within a stack, or even a parbox as a stack element.